# Split cells to different rows by formula

Tags: excel

I have a table like this

```
Column1 Column2
a   m
a   n m
b   j k l u
c   o
d   f g
d   k l n
```

And I want to split cells that have different items that is separated by space to different rows like this

```
Column1 Column2
a   m
a   m
a   n
b   j
b   k
b   l
b   u
c   o
```

In your idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `Sheet1` and result is to be displayed in `Sheet2`. Try the following code:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastcolumn As Long, rowCnt As Long
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet
    Dim dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object
    Dim arr() As String, temp As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    'set your sheets here
    Set dataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'get last row with data in Sheet1
    lastRow = dataWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    rowCnt = 1
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        temp = dataWS.Cells(i, 2).Value
        'get each value in Column B separated by space " "
        arr = Split(temp, " ")
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'add values in dictionary
            dict1.Add Item:=dataWS.Cells(i, 1).Value, Key:=rowCnt
            dict2.Add Item:=arr(j), Key:=rowCnt
            rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    'display result in Sheet2
    outputWS.Range("A1").Resize(dict1.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict1.items)
    outputWS.Range("B1").Resize(dict2.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict2.items)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

See image for reference:

[image]